# PendingIntent to the same service?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

In my mainactivity I start service.

In service I have a pendingintent to show notifications to users every 15 minutes:

my AlarmReceiver class:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends Service {
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

showNotify();

 AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intentn = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intentn, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        alarmMgr.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + (1000 * 900), pendingIntent);
    }
    else {
        alarmMgr.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + (1000 * 900), pendingIntent);
    }
```

So I'd like to repeate the alarm in my service to show notifications every 15 min. The problem is it is never repeating. I try flag_update_current, and others but I think the problem isn't the flags... Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can Use `WorkManager` instead of service.Initial `workmanager` in the `Application` class.

```
 override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        WorkManager.initialize(
            this,
            Configuration.Builder()
                .setWorkerFactory(appComponent.factoryAppWorker())
                .build()
        )
        initWorkManager()
    }
    private fun initWorkManager(){
        Log.d("MainRepository","initWorkManager")
        val constraints = Constraints.Builder()
            .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED)
            .build()

        val notificationRequest =
            PeriodicWorkRequestBuilder<PullNotificationWorker>(15, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .setConstraints(constraints)
                .build()
        WorkManager.getInstance(this)
           .enqueueUniquePeriodicWork(PULL_PERIODIC_NOTIFICATION_WORK_NAME,ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.REPLACE,notificationRequest)

    }
```

And `workmanager` class should like this:

```
    class PullNotificationWorker @AssistedInject constructor(
        @Assisted private val appContext: Context,
        @Assisted private val params: WorkerParameters,
        private val repository: MainRepository
    ) : CoroutineWorker(appContext, params) {
    
        override suspend fun doWork(): Result = coroutineScope{
            Log.d(TAG,"doWork")
            try {
                    createNotification(it)
                }
                 Result.success()
    
            } catch (throwable: Throwable) {
                Log.d(TAG,"work faile=${throwable.message}")
                 Result.failure()
            }
        }
}
```

For more information read android developer docs.[workmanager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing `PendingIntent.getService` to `PendingIntent.getBroadcast` instead? It works for me.

Here is the code that I'm using:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(code, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    am.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC, time, pIntent);

    //Do something
  }
}
```